# TMP C++ and parameter packs

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<std::size_t... Is>
void unlock_(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {

    iter(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);
}
```

Let's consider above example. I cannot understand `iter(std::get<Is>(tuple)...);`. I know that `...` is expanding "operator". So it should be applied to parameter pack ( in sense arguments) or template paremeter packs.
And I can imagine what is `std::index_sequence<Is...>`. Because `Is` is template parameter pack it should be just `1, 2, 3, 4, ...` ( for example) .
In that case out parameter is specific because it is not type. It is `size_t`.

But here: `std::get<Is>(tuple)...);` `std::get<Is>(tuple)` doesn't return parameter/template pack so I cannot context of usage.

P.S. Is it possible to see how the code looks after meta-programming? Similarly to after preprocessing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The entire expression containing the pack variable is expanded, so you get `std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple)`, ....

Comment: The [pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) section of the [cppreference page for parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) explains how this works.

Comment: Parameter pack expansion is quite complex, and expands the whole expression, rather than the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a method of expanding a `std::tuple` by generating a compile-time sequence of indices.

`...` in this context expands forms containing unexpanded parameter packs. It will generate a list like this:

```
Is...
0,1,2,...

doSomething(Is)...
doSomething(0), doSomething(1), doSomething(2), ...

doSomething(Is...)
doSomething(0,1,2,...)

std::get<Is>(tuple)...
std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple), ...

iter(std::get<Is>(tuple)...)
iter(std::get<0>(tuple), std::get<1>(tuple), std::get<2>(tuple), ...)
```

The effect is that `iter` is called with arguments extracted from the tuple.